# Enabling/Disabling actions from another action

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, action, netbeans-platform

I have a callback action called AddAction. When AddAction is pressed I want it to enable all the components on the TopComponent as well as disable several of the other actions on the toolbar. Then when the SaveAction is pressed it saves the data to the database, enables the other actions and disables all the components on the TC.

Right now I have AddAction setup to enable all the components but I can't figure out how to disable the other actions as well.

AddAction

```
@ActionID(
    category = "1",
id = "com.waudware.Actions.AddAction")
@ActionRegistration(
    iconBase = "com/waudware/Actions/Icons/add.png",
    displayName = "#CTL_AddAction",
    key = "AddAction")
@ActionReferences({
    @ActionReference(path = "Menu/Record", position = 3333),
    @ActionReference(path = "Toolbars/AddEditDelete", position = 100)
})
@Messages("CTL_AddAction=Add")
public final class EditAction implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }
}
```

TopComponent

```
public RouteTopComponent() {
        initComponents();
        setName(Bundle.CTL_RouteTopComponent());
        setToolTipText(Bundle.HINT_RouteTopComponent());

        getActionMap().put("AddAction", new AbstractAction(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                addRoute(true);
            }
        });
}

private void addRoute(boolean add) {
        txtRoute.setEnabled(add);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

- [Swing Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) has method [setEnabled(boolean b)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29)
- have look at [boolean isEnabled()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html#isEnabled%28%29) and very usefull [get/putValue(String key, Object value)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html#putValue%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: I think I might be misunderstanding the answer, but the NetBeans platform doesn't use the swing Action, it auto generates a class that implements the ActionListener and as far I can tell it doesn't have a setEnabled() method.

Answer (score 0):

What I do:

```
getActionMap().get("AddAction").setEnabled(true | false);
```

You can also enable / disable / hide the whole toolbar

```
Toolbar toolbar;

toolbar = ToolbarPool.getDefault().findToolbar("toolbarName");
if (toolbar != null) {
    toolbar.setVisible(true | false);    // show / hide
    toolbar.setEnabled(true | false);    // enable / disable
}
```